# Chemspider returns no value when run within a class

Tags: python, api, oop, tkinter

I'm trying to create a chemistry moles calculator using Python and the Chemspider API. I got this code working, which searches the database by name:

===THIS WORKS FINE===

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    import chemspipy
    from chemspipy import ChemSpider
    cs = ##MY CHEMSPIDER ID
    def NameSearch(*args, **kwargs):

        namesearch = tk.Tk()
        namesearch.title("Search via Name")

        def ChemSearch(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                ChemName = ChemicalName.get()
                ChemName = cs.search(ChemName)
                if len(ChemName) >= 1:
                    ChemicalID.set(ChemName[0])
                    print(ChemicalID)
                else:
                    popupmsg("Sorry, we could not find that chemical. Please try again")
            except ValueError:
                pass

        searchframe = ttk.Frame(namesearch)
        searchframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")
        searchframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        searchframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        ChemicalName = tk.StringVar()
        ChemicalID = tk.StringVar()

        Chemical_entry = ttk.Entry(searchframe, width=7, textvariable=ChemicalName)
        Chemical_entry.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky="we")

        ttk.Label(searchframe, textvariable=ChemicalID).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=("ew"))
        ttk.Button(searchframe, text="Search", command=ChemSearch).grid(column=3, row=4, sticky="w")

        ttk.Label(searchframe, text="Chemical Name").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="w")
        ttk.Label(searchframe, text="The ID of this chemical is: ").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky="e")

        for child in searchframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

        Chemical_entry.focus()
        namesearch.bind("<Return>", ChemSearch)

    NameSearch()
```

I then decided to implement a menu for my program using tkinter like this:

```
cs = ##MY CHEMSPIDER ID

def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Tk()

    def leavemini():
        popup.destroy()
    popup.wm_title("!")
    label = ttk.Label(popup, text=msg)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    B1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command = leavemini)
    B1.pack()

def NameSearch(cs, *args, **kwargs):

    namesearch = tk.Tk()
    namesearch.title("Search via Name")

    def ChemSearch(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            ChemName = ChemicalName.get()
            ChemName = cs.search(ChemName)
            if len(ChemName) >= 1:
                ChemicalID.set(ChemName[0])
            else:
                popupmsg("Sorry, we could not find that chemical. Please try again")
                print(ChemicalID)
        except ValueError:
            print("a")
            pass

    searchframe = ttk.Frame(namesearch)
    searchframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")
    searchframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    searchframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    ChemicalName = tk.StringVar()
    ChemicalID = tk.StringVar()

    Chemical_entry = ttk.Entry(searchframe, width=7, textvariable=ChemicalName)
    Chemical_entry.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky="we")

    ttk.Label(searchframe, textvariable=ChemicalID).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=("ew"))
    ttk.Button(searchframe, text="Search", command=ChemSearch).grid(column=3, row=4, sticky="w")

    ttk.Label(searchframe, text="Chemical Name").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="w")
    ttk.Label(searchframe, text="The ID of this chemical is: ").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky="e")

    for child in searchframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

    Chemical_entry.focus()
    namesearch.bind("<Return>", ChemSearch)

class ChemApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Chemistry App")

        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        menubar = tk.Menu(container)
        searchmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        searchmenu.add_command(label="Search by Name", command=lambda: NameSearch(cs))
        searchmenu.add_separator()
        searchmenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Search", menu=searchmenu)



        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage,):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Start Page")
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Search for a Chemical",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(NameSearch))
        button.pack()

app = ChemApp()
app.geometry("1280x720")
app.mainloop()
```

However when run through a function triggered by the pressing of a tkinter menu button (under search in the GUI), it refuses to return a correct value from the database. As far as I'm aware, I've passed all the required variables, and it is running in an identical environment to before, it just won't work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as it has been troubling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have more than once instance of `Tk` in an application. You need to call `Tk()` exactly once. If you need more windows, create instances of `Toplevel`.